# get product small image url not working with resize

Tags: image

i want to get product image url from id

i wrote below code but it not working

```
$baseproductimage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('223')->getSmallImage()->resize($list_image_width,$list_image_height);
```

Comment: Hi mour and welcome to MageOverflow. Please learn how to write questions: Add what happens, and what you expect. What is the error which occurs, if any. If not, write it down.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<?php $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('223'); ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($products,'small_image')->resize($list_image_width,$list_image_height); ?>
```